# First Order Hold discrete-time approximation to first order continuous-time linear system

Tags: discretization

Consider the following first order linear system described by:

$\tau \frac{d}{dt}y(t)=-y(t) + x(t)$.

I have seen a discrete time approximation to this system using a "First Order Hold" approximation of the form:

$y[k+1] = e^{-T/\tau} y[k] + [-e^{-T/\tau} + \tau/T(1-e^{-T/\tau})]x[k] + [1 - \tau/T(1-e^{-T/\tau})]x[k+1]$ where $T$ is the sampling period.

Can anyone show a derivation of this result?

Comment: hmmm.  this might be interesting.  i can speculate at an answer.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson. Please do!  Other discrete-time approximations to continuous linear, time invariant systems (forward/backward difference, impulse invariance, root matching, bilinear transform) are all well-explained in the DSP literature.   Haven't seen this one covered in any depth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution comes from assuming that
$$
x(t) = x[k] + \frac{x[k+1]-x[k]}{T}(t-kT), \ \ t\in[kT,(k+1)T)
$$
where $x[k]:=x(kT)$, this is, a first order hold or a linear interpolation of $x[k]$ and $x[k+1]$ in between $kT$ and $(k+1)T$. Now, we simply compute the EXPLICIT solution of the differential equation (at instants $t=kT$) by integrating it from $t=kT$ towards $t=(k+1)T$. This should be enough to derive the result but let me get into more detail. First, multiply the ODE by $\frac{1}{\tau}e^{t/\tau}$ to obtain:
$$
\frac{dy}{dt}e^{t/\tau} + \frac{1}{\tau}e^{t/\tau}y(t) = \frac{1}{\tau}e^{t/\tau}x(t)
$$
and notice that $\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{t/\tau}y(t)\right) = \frac{dy}{dt}e^{t/\tau} + \frac{1}{\tau}e^{t/\tau}y(t)$ and thus:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{t/\tau}y(t)\right) = \frac{1}{\tau}e^{t/\tau}x(t)
$$
Now integrate both sides:
$$
\int_{kT}^{(k+1)T}\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{t/\tau}y(t)\right)dt = \int_{kT}^{(k+1)T}\frac{1}{\tau}e^{t/\tau}x(t)dt
$$
the left hand side results (by fundamental theorem of calculus) into:
$$
\int_{kT}^{(k+1)T}\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{t/\tau}y(t)\right)dt = \left.e^{t/\tau}y(t)\right|_{kT}^{(k+1)T}  =e^{(k+1)T/\tau}y[k+1] - e^{kT/\tau}y[k]
$$
Thus,
$$
e^{(k+1)T/\tau}y[k+1] = e^{kT/\tau}y[k] + \int_{kT}^{(k+1)T}\frac{1}{\tau}e^{t/\tau}x(t)dt
$$
Now, simply divide by $e^{(k+1)T/\tau}$ to obtain
$$
y[k+1] = e^{-T/\tau}y[k] + e^{-(k+1)T/\tau}\int_{kT}^{(k+1)T}\frac{1}{\tau}e^{t/\tau}x(t)dt
$$
As you can see we are almost done. We just have to compute:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&e^{-(k+1)T/\tau}\int_{kT}^{(k+1)T}\frac{1}{\tau}e^{t/\tau}x(t)dt =\\ &e^{-(k+1)T/\tau}\int_{kT}^{(k+1)T}\frac{1}{\tau}e^{t/\tau}\left(x[k] + \frac{x[k+1]-x[k]}{T}(t-kT)\right)dt
\end{aligned} 
$$
which we can do explicitly since $x[k]$ and $x[k+1]$ are just constants. After some algebra you can factor terms with $x[k]$ and terms with $x[k+1]$ and you will obtain precisely what you wanted. If you want to check, I plugged this into wolfram alpha [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%28integral%20exp%28-%28k%2B1%29T%2Ftau%29*exp%28t%2Ftau%29*%28x1%20%2B%20%28t-kT%29*%28x2-x1%29%2FT%29%2Ftau%20dt%20from%20kT%20to%20%28k%2B1%29T%29) ("x1" is $x[k]$ and "x2" is $x[k+1]$).

This kind of discretizations are nice since, if $x(t)$ does behave as a piece-wise linear continuous function, the discretization is NOT an approximation, but an equivalent (and exact) representation of the ODE, this is: since it was obtained by explicit computation of the solution of the ODE, no information is lost about the output samples $y[k]$. (in contrast to approximating $dy/dt \approx (y[k+1]-y[k])/T$ or some other approximation as the bilinear one)

**NEW REMARK:** I just want to point out that this same procedure can be performed for other high order systems, or even for other types of holders. Recall that any LTI system with scalar input $x$ and scalar output $y$ can be represented by its transfer function, or equivalently by a state space representation
$$
\frac{dz}{dt} = Az + Bx,\ \ \  y = Cz
$$
with $z(t)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n$ the order of the system, $A$ a square matrix, $B$ a column vector and $C$ a row vector. Recall that the poles of the transfer function are the eigenvalues of $A$ and zeros of the transfer function depend only on the coefficients on contained in $C$. Thus, we can solve for the system on $y[k]$ explicitly using a similar procedure as before:
$$
z[k+1] = e^{AT}z[k] + e^{A(k+1)T}\int_{kT}^{(k+1)T}e^{-A\tau}Bx(\tau)d\tau, \ \ y[k]=Cz[k]
$$
where $e^{A\tau}$ is the exponential matrix. Finally, plugging in the particular form of $x(t)$ results in the final form of the discretization (in discrete time state space representation). This can be used to derive (exact or "consistent") discretizations for ZOH, FOH, high order holders or more exotic holders.

Comment: appears to be a good answer.  keep in mind that this FOH is not causal if $x[k]$ is the present moment of time.  BTW, there is another model of FOH that is more bizzare.  i'm glad you haven't used it.  thank you for saving me the effort.  all i can do is give you 10 points.

Comment: Of course, I agree about the causality issue. However, its the simplest assumption to derive the discretization the OP asked for. Thanks sir!

Comment: there's an [article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_hold).  the version of FOH you used is the first one shown

Comment: Nice remark! What happened is that I noticed the acausality in the original question's discrete system, so this FOH was my first guess. Im glad that it worked on the first try too

Comment: @RodrigoAldana Is there a missing factor of 1/tau in the argument to the the exponent in front of the last three integrals?  Also, perhaps rusty on ODE's but how does integrating only from kT to (k+1)T solve the ODE?

Comment: Indeed, there was a missing factor of $1/\tau$ in those exponents, sorry about that. Fortunately, I made that mistake only when writing the answer, and does not change the conclusion (I plugged it correctly in wolfram, or you can verify it by hand).

Comment: By solving the ode, I mean the following. The ODE has a continuous time solution $y(t)$, which would be the complete solution for all $t$. However, we only care about $y[k+1]:=y((k+1)T)$. You can obtain it as follows: assume you know $y[k]$, then, solve the ODE with initial condition $y[k]$ in order to obtain $y(t)$. Finally, evaluate for $t=(k+1)T$ to obtain $y[k+1]$. We can skip the middle step of obtaining $y(t)$ by integrating from $kT$ all the way to $(k+1)T$.

Comment: Otherwise (if you wanted to obtain $y(t)$), we would have done
$$
\int_{kT}^t \frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{t/\tau}y(t)\right)dt = e^{t/\tau}y(t) - e^{kT/\tau}y[k]
$$
and then solving for $y(t)$ in order to obtain what we would strictly call the solution to the ODE. However, evaluating this at $t=(k+1)T$ and having integrated all the way to $(k+1)T$ right from the beginning doesn't change the result. Let me know if this is clear enough.

Comment: I added some additional info on how this procedure can be extended to high order systems, or other types of holders, in case you are interested.

Comment: @RodrigoAldana Clearly the solution is required only at $kT$ for all integers $k$.  The final recursion suggests that at $(k+1)T$, $y[k]$ is already known.  In general, one would think that the limits should be $\int^{(k+1)T}_{-\infty}$.  How does knowledge of $y[k]$ enable us to change the lower limit?   Is it because of the piecewise linear nature of the input?  Should this be viewed as a new ODE for each k with input equal to zero outside $[kT, (k+1)T)$?

Comment: Why would the limits need to be $\int_{-\infty}^{(k+1)T}$? In general the idea is: you want to obtain the expression of $y[k+1]$ in terms of $y[k]$ to obtain an equivalent discrete system. Hence, you are assuming that you know $y[k]$, and you can solve the ode (and then evaluating the solution at $t=(k+1)T$) with initial condition y[k] at $t=kT$ to obtain $y[k+1]$. Since you know $y[k]$, you don't need any other knowledge for what happened for $t<kT$. Perhaps you can use $\int_{-\infty}^{(k+1)T}$, but we chose to pick the limits as $\int_{kT}^{(k+1)T}$ because the result is useful.

Comment: Regarding the last part of what you asked. the piece-wise linear nature of the input doesn't have anything to do actually. The nature of the input only changes the form of the last integral implying that will only have an impact on coefficients multiplying the input in the discretization. Moreover, you don't need to view it as a new ODE with input equal to zero outside the interval: as I suggested above, if you know $y[k]$ then you don't need to know anything about what happened before $t<kT$ in order to know what happens for $t>kT$.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your question, or I missed your point? please let me know.

Comment: @RodrigoAldana: It seems that your solution to the ODE is based on the integrating factor method, right?

Comment: You are right. _

Comment: OK.  I think I've convinced myself that this makes sense.